# How to make bitwise add in c#?

Tags: c#, types, operators, bit, addition

I am trying to program a PLC address generator. However there I need to make bit wise addition to find the next available address.

Meaning if I start with the adress 0.0 and add 2 bit then the next free adress would be 0.3. It goes up until 0.7 then then next adress is 1.0 up to 1.7 then 2.0 and so on.

Depending on what datatype I add to the addition the next free adress should be calculated.

For example a bool is one bit. 0.1 -> 0.2 -> 0.3 and so on
A Byte has 8 bits if I add a byte and the last free adress was 0.4 the next free address should be 2.0.

A Word has 16 Bits so 0.0 -> 2.0 -> 4.0 and so on.

A Double Word has 32 Bits so 0.0 -> 4.0 -> 8.0 and so on.

I am looking for an implementation in c# where I can add the different types as input and it adds it and gives me corresponding address and stores then next free address internal for the next operation.

For example:

```
    Type         Startaddress
1   Bool         0.0            (->0.1)
2   Bool         0.1            (->0.2)
3   Byte         1.0            (->1.7) as 8 bits are required
4   Bool         2.0            (->2.1) 
5   Word         3.0            (->4.7) as 16 bits are required
6   Double Word  5.0            (->8.7) as 32 bits are required
```

Any idea how I could implement that apart from a lot of if else and loop? I am looking for an elegant overloaded operator approach.

Comment: "if I add a byte and the last free address was 0.4 the next free address should be 2.0" how is that calculated?

Comment: @JakubDąbek: That one isn't making much sense to me either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "trick" to your problem is the notation of .0-.7 for bit addresses and the C# types don't match up exactly with the types in your specification.

The main class I show here stores the address as bit offset internally, and provides the integer and decimal fraction through the fAddress() method.

Your example shows alignment on byte boundaries, but doesn't align words or double words--so that's what I implemented. Comments show how to do that differently if the PLC cares.

You'll need to add the code to store values at the byte.bit type addresses.

```
using System;

namespace PLCAddress
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PLCAddress a = new PLCAddress();
            float address;
            bool boolA = true;
            byte byteA = 7;
            ushort wordA = 65535;
            uint dblwordA = 4294967295;

            address = a.Store(boolA);
            Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());

            address = a.Store(boolA);
            Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());

            address = a.Store(byteA);
            Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());

            address = a.Store(boolA);
            Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());

            address = a.Store(wordA);
            Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());

            address = a.Store(dblwordA);
            Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());
        }
    }
    public class PLCAddress
    {
        protected uint _address;
        public PLCAddress()
        {
            _address = 0;
        }

        public float Store(bool b)
        {
            float rv = fAddress();
            _address += 1;
            return rv;
        }
        public float Store(byte b)
        {
            float rv = fAddress(8);
            _address += 8;
            return rv;
        }
        public float Store(ushort b)
        {
            float rv = fAddress(8); // use fAddress(16) if words need to be on word boundaries
            _address += 16;
            return rv;
        }
        public float Store(uint b)
        {
            float rv = fAddress(8); // use fAddress(32) if double words need to be on double word boundaries
            _address += 32;
            return rv;
        }

        protected float fAddress()
        {
            return (float)Whole + (float)Fraction / 10;
        }

        protected float fAddress(uint alignment)
        {
            uint roundup = alignment - 1;
            uint mask = ~roundup;
            uint AlignedAddress = _address + roundup;
            AlignedAddress = AlignedAddress & mask;
            _address = AlignedAddress;
            return fAddress();
        }
        protected uint Whole
        {
            get { return _address / 8; }
        }
        protected uint Fraction
        {
            get { return _address % 8;  }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store these addresses in an int - the lower part in the first 3 bits, the rest in the rest of the bits and get the address from there. This allows you to do normal arithmetic on these addresses and numbers. If the address is in a string you can do something like this:

```
public static int ToIntAddress(this string str)
{
    var values = str.Split('.');
    int lower = int.Parse(values[1]);
    int higher = int.Parse(values[0]) << 3;
    return lower + higher;
}

public static string ToAddress(this int address) => $"{address >> 3}.{address & 0b0111}";

("3.0".ToIntAddress() + 15).ToAddress() // "4.7"
("5.0".ToIntAddress() + 31).ToAddress() // "8.7"
("0.4".ToIntAddress() + 7).ToAddress()  // "1.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer an object oriented approach:

```
public class MemoryManager
{
    private int _dataSize = 0;

    public enum DataTypes
    {
        Bool = 1,
        Byte = 8,
        Word = 16,
        DWord = 32
    }
    public MemoryLocation Add(DataTypes type)
    {            
        var address = GetCurrentAddress();
        _dataSize += (int)type;
        return address;
    }

    private MemoryLocation GetCurrentAddress()
    {
        int currentByteLocation = _dataSize / 8;
        int currentBitLocation = _dataSize % 8;            
        return new MemoryLocation(currentByteLocation, currentBitLocation);
    }        
}

public class MemoryLocation
{
    public MemoryLocation(int byteLocation, int bitIndex)
    {
        ByteLocation = byteLocation;
        BitIndex = bitIndex;            
    }
    public int ByteLocation { get; private set; }
    public int BitIndex { get; private set; }        
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0},{1}]", ByteLocation, BitIndex);
    }
}
```

I whipped this out real quick but you can use other more streamlined methods to generate the next address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public int BitWiseAdd()
{
            int FirstNumber = 50;
            int SecondNumber = 60;
            while (SecondNumber !=0)
            {

                int carry = FirstNumber & SecondNumber;
                FirstNumber = FirstNumber ^ SecondNumber;
                SecondNumber = carry << 1;
            }
            return FirstNumber;


}
```